# How to fetch data from store in redux-saga?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I have stored a payload in the redux store. I couldn't access the store object. How to access the `store` object? I wanted to access it by redux-saga. I tried even by normal redux to access store but could'nt!

Comment: Use the `select` effect. Checkout it's description in the API documentaiton: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to access it by redux-saga. I tried even by normal redux to access store but could'nt!

In general case `redux-saga` combines two things - `redux` middleware and independent process manager. If you need only to fetch and directly manipulate with redux internal state without process managing, probably, it's better to write own simple middleware (https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html ) and maybe compose it with saga.

Of course, you can easily use `select` effect (https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#selectselector-args ). but take in account, that middleware first forwards the action to the reducers and then notifies the Sagas. This means that when you query the Store's State, you get the State after the action has been applied.
Most likely it's better to store mandatory information info current `saga`'s closure, for example, before `while-true` loop in dedicated saga process.

```
function* someSaga() {
    const localState = {};
    while(true) {
        const action = yield take('ACTION_PATTERN');
        // some logic to dispatch the action
        yield put('SOME_AFTER_ACTION')
    }
}
```